# How to automatically move files from one server to another servers - not syncing but moving

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I need to securely and automatically move files from several "inboxes" on one Windows 2019 server to several "outboxes" on other Windows 2019 servers. The servers are located behind secure firewalls, thus I would like to refrain from using smb (robocopy, etc.).

I was looking at several sync tools (i.e. syncthing), but those are more about syncing than moving files.

Requirements:

- Unattended move of files
- Not using smb (sftp, proprietary protocol ok), must be controllable in firewall
- If possible GUI for configuration and control
- Logging of move operations

Any suggestions how to solve this is very welcome.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a company that had this as in internal workflow. We had a Perl script that would use rsync over SSH on the backend. Once the copy was complete (verification of md5 before and after copy), it would delete. Of course, it wrote a log.

You're asking for a product recommendation which is off-topic for this site, but here's a way you could do it yourself. Scripting of this sort is entirely within the realm of duties for a systems administrator.

Answer (score 1):

A "move" is really just a "copy + delete"

Any commercial product that does a "move" is just going to do:

- Copy file FROM source TO dest
- Verify copy on dest
- If verification passes:

  - Delete source
- Else:

  - Exit with error
- Output results of all steps to a log

These steps are all easily scriptable on any modern OS without adding any additional tools.